# how to assign unique id's to dynamically added row using partial views in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Similar questions have been asked in the past but I m finding a bit hard to find the solution to this issue.

I have a simple partial view as below

```
@model MemberSiteAddressModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Site) </td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AddressLine1)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.AddressLine2)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.City)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.PostCode)</td>
</tr>
```

My main view loads the partial view via ajax call as below. I need to give unique id's to any new added row (As I will need to add more details on any selected row) and fields so that I can use the model binder

```
<table id="businessSitesTable" class="table table-responsive">
   <tr>
    <th>Site Name</th>
    <th>Address Line 1</th>
    <th>Address Line 2</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>PostCode</th>
  </tr>
 </table>

<script>
function LoadPartial() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AddNewRow",
            content: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {                   
                $("#sitesTable").append(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
}
```

```
<input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="LoadPartial(); return false;" />
```

Comment: Don't use incremental `id` attributes. It's a pain to calculate them, and worse to maintain them. Use DOM traversal to find the values you need from the element that raised the event.

Comment: Can you kindly give an example? thanks

Comment: What do you need to do with the input elements that you append from the partial view?

Comment: or use a `data-id` attribute (perhaps on the `tr`) to push an identifying bit of `MemberSiteAddressModel` into the view to allow the client side script to rehydrate properly. Or render an `Html.HiddenFor` if it needs to be posted back....

Comment: Use record`s primary key

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I will add a `Save` button at the end of each row and post the entire row to the controller on this button click. @Tetsujin I guess there is no identifying field as its an insertor for a model at this point

Comment: Q: Do you intend for the entire table to be posted back at once on submit?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I won't need to post back the entire table. Just the individual rows using a `Save` button. It will be present at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well start with a client-side template (hidden row you clone). You are Ajax-getting an *empty set of controls* which is pretty wasteful.

As you are not posting back the entire table, just a row at a time I assume, you do not need IDs on the field at all, just the names.

Use `@Html.Partial` to render a single template dummy record inline, or just insert the HTML you want direct to a template:

```
<table id="template" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Site"/></td>
        <td><input name="AddressLine1"/></td>
        <td><input name="AddressLine2"/></td>
        <td><input name="City"/></td>
        <td><input name="PostCode"/>)</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="saverow" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: If you decide to inject via @Html.Partial, as it uses `EditorFor` you will need to strip the ID's completely from the clone.

Then just use like this on add button press:

```
function LoadPartial() {
    $("#sitesTable").append($('#template').html());
}
```

The `save` option (you have not shown) should then take all the inputs on the row and Ajax post them as the  `data` property. This uses a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.saverow', function(){
     vare $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
     // $ajax put call of the current row's fields here
});
```

The selector runs at *event time*, so it will work with dynamic elements.

Note: Please do not mix inline event handlers with jQuery. Just do the events "the JQuery way" instead so that the *event registration* is not separated from the *event handler*:

```
 $('#addBtn').click(function(){
     $("#sitesTable").append($('#template').html());
 });
```

This is easier to maintain than inline handlers and supports multiple handlers and other cool jQuery event features :)

Comment: Perfect @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0):

Your use of "id" here is confusing, as I really think you're talking about an index for a list. If you want to be able to actually receive the values posted for these dynamically added items, the input names must be properly indexed. I don't have your view model to work from, but generally speaking the generated HTML would have to look something like:

```
<input type="text" name="BusinessSites[0].Site" />
```

The chief problem you're going to have is keeping this index updated while adding / removing items from the page. To do this as painlessly and efficiently as possible, you should either employ some client-side library that can handle model binding HTML (Knockout, Angular, etc.) or you can use non-sequential indexes as described in [Phil Haack's post *Model Binding to a List*](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: If you check the comments, they do not need to post back the entire form. Just individual rows. There is no specific need to match the MVC generated HTML at all, or even to load the blank rows via Ajax.